# Fetch date time part from filename in R

Tags: r, regex, filenames, gsub

I want to fetch date and time part from the filename as given below:

```
filename<-"/abc/def/ghi/jk.0m25.2015011500.f264.path2.pathd254004.nc"
```

I tried the below code to fetch the desired part:

```
 dt<- sub('^[^.]+.(\\d+)+[\\w\\d].*','\\1',filename)#Not working
```

Here date and time part is date:20150115 time:00

```
dtm <- strptime(c("2015-01-15 00:00:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz = "EST")
```

Then I want to add hours(which is **264** in the filename (/.f**264**.path2.)) to the dtm object.

```
final_dt<- dtm+264(hrs)
```

final_dt contains both date and time.

Once I get value of final_dt, then I want to add this as a column to the dataframe as given below:

```
# Creating dataframe 
long<-c(106.61291,-81.97224,-84.4277,-97.66631,-72.68604)
lat<-c(35.04333,33.37378,33.64073,30.19743,41.93887)
xy <- data.frame(long, lat)

#Desired Output
  actual_date time Final_date time     long      lat
1 2015-01-15  00   2015-01-26 ...        106.61291 35.04333
2 2015-01-15  00   2015-01-26 ...        -81.97224 33.37378
3 2015-01-15  00   2015-01-26 ...         -84.42770 33.64073
4 2015-01-15  00   2015-01-26 ...          -97.66631 30.19743
5 2015-01-15  00   2015-01-26 ...          -72.68604 41.93887
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll try my best to clear this up, but let me start by saying your question is unclear,

> ```
> dt<- sub('^[^.]+.(\\d+)+[\\w\\d].*','\\1',filename)#Not working
> ```

It appears that you are asking for a solution to that part?

Assuming the date time is the only sequence of 10 digits in a row that can appear in your filename, you can use the following regex

```
"\.\d{10}\."
```

Then parse the sub strings (YYYY, MM, DD, TT) into a date-time by using substring function. and pass that to your strptime method.

```
final_dt<- dtm+264(hrs)
```

For the addition/increment of time intervals, strptime appears to accept integers as *seconds* so you could try

```
final_dt<- dtm + (264*60*60)
```

Where 60*60 is 60 minutes/hour * 60 seconds/minute unit conversion.

```
xy <- data.frame(long, lat)
```

If you have all the dtm's in a vector, you can use them at the time of creation of xy such as:

```
xy  <- data.frame(dtm_vector, long, lat)
```

(p.s. you should try adding more tags to your question, such as 'regex', since that is the biggest hurdle in this scenario)